# Analysis of parallel arm study

Tags: multilevel-analysis, model, intervention-analysis

I have a two arm intervention study (Arm1: Exercise only, Arm2: Exercise plus diet). Aim of the study is to compare the influence of exercise and diet as compared to exercise only on weight (continuous) and perceived health (Ordinal variable). I have only the last (after six months of the study) data (cross-sectional) only. I want to analyse this. I have a number of covariates like age, sex, TV watch time, etc. 
I intend to use multi-level model to assess difference in the two groups as we have different schools so schools will be treated as random effect.

My model looks like this 
BMI = age + sex + TV(time) + Intervention (group1 vs group2) + School (Random effect)

Now I wonder whether this is correct to specify intervention as a variable in the model. We do not have change from baseline. 
What else could be a good strategy?

Best

Comment: Was school part of the study design (i.e. a cluster randomised trial) or is it more generally felt to be of interest to treat it as a random effect?

Comment: @JamesStanley: It wasn't a cluster randomized trial as whole school was not involved. But as children come from schools so we thought it would be of interest to treat it is random.